# uploadify can not get server response data

Tags: node.js, upload, express, uploadify

I use uploadify with express.js to upload video to node server, it work fine, but after I generate the video thumbnail I need to return the thumbnail path, here is what I did

```
exports.upload = function(req, res,next){
    var tmp_path = req.files.product_video.path;
    var target_path = 'F:/shopping/shop/' +req.body.shop_id+'/'+ req.files.product_video.name;

    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err)
                }else{
                    exec("C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i shop/"+ req.body.shop_id+ '/' + req.files.product_video.name  + " -ss 00:01:00.00 -r 1 -an -vframes 1 -s 250x150 -f mjpeg shop/"+ req.body.shop_id+ '/'  + req.files.product_video.name  + "_thumbnail.jpg", function(err){
                        // res.send({'thumb' : 'shop/'+ req.body.shop_id+ '/'  + req.files.product_video.name  + "_thumbnail.jpg",});
                        var data = {
                            'thum_src':'shop/'+ req.body.shop_id+ '/'  + req.files.product_video.name  + "_thumbnail.jpg"
                        }
                        res.send(data);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

here is frontend code

```
function addVideo(){
    $('#input_product_video').uploadify({
        'formData':{'shop_id':$('#shop_id').val()},
        'buttonText'    : 'add video',
        'fileSizeLimit' : '100MB',
        'fileObjName' : 'product_video',
        'uploader'    : '/uploads',
        'swf'         :'/public/javascripts/lib/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'onUploadSuccess':function(file,data){
            console.log(data.thum_src);

        }
    });
}
```

the

```
console.log(data.thum_src); // always end of "undefined"
```

but

```
 console.log(data) ; //will output the json data like this
                                         {
                                            'thum_src':'path'
                                          }
```

I don't get it ??? why can't I access thum_src like data.thum_src ???

well it looks like it's not a object but a string, weird

Answer (score 0):

your response in the server code need to add header {Content-Type:'application/json'} or else the default is to interpret as text. or u can do JSON.parse(data) to convert the text to json object in front end.

Comment: but the express doc says When an Array or Object is given Express will respond with the JSON representation:

Comment: just check the response header. btw what browser,browser version,express version.